# ObjectInputStream Blocking socket external ip madness

Tags: java, sockets, connection, timeout, objectinputstream

When I initialize my objectinputstreams, after I have initialized and flushed by objectoutputstreams, I get this:

Client:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at Start.refreshChangeLog(Start.java:87)
>       at Start$2.windowOpened(Start.java:234)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Server:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at Client.(Client.java:27)
>       at ThreadAccept.run(ThreadAccept.java:23)

And my client code:

```
public void refreshChangeLog() {
    Socket logSocket = null;
    ObjectInputStream input = null;
    ObjectOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        logSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server), 21992);
        logSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(logSocket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(logSocket.getInputStream());
        output.writeObject("type:changeLog");
        output.flush();
        Object o = input.readObject();
        while (o instanceof String && !((String) o).equals("done")) {
            String msg = (String) o;
            int index = msg.indexOf("|");
            if (index > -1) {
                changeLogMap.put(msg.substring(0, index), msg.substring(index + 1));
                changeLogList.addItem(msg.substring(0, index));
            }
            o = input.readObject();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loadLocalChangeLog();
    }
    if (changeLogList.getItemCount() > 0) {
        changeLogList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        File changelog = new File(path + "changelog");
        if (!changelog.exists() || !changelog.isDirectory()) {
            changelog.mkdirs();
        }
        for (String key : changeLogMap.keySet()) {
            File changef = new File(changelog, key + ".txt");
            if (!changef.exists()) {
                try {
                    changef.createNewFile();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (changef.exists()) {
                PrintWriter writer;
                try {
                    writer = new PrintWriter(changef);
                    writer.write(changeLogMap.get(key));
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
            output = null;
        }
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
            input = null;
        }
        if (logSocket != null) {
            logSocket.close();
            logSocket = null;
        }
    }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

And my Server code:

```
socket = new ServerSocket(21992);
        new Client.ThreadUpdateLobby();
        while (Start.frame != null && socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
            Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
            Client client = new Client(clientSocket);
            if (client.isValid) {
                synchronized (clients) {
                    clients.add(client);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(50L);
        }`
```

More server code:

```
this.socket = socket;
    try {
        this.socket = socket;
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        listener = new ThreadListen(this, input);
        isValid = true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
                output = null;
            }
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
                input = null;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
                this.socket = null;
            }
        }catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        isValid = false;
    }`
```

I've been at a loss, apparently the header isn't flushing? Therefor the inputstream just sits and waits. The problem appears to be client side. Also, this only happens if I use my external network ip(98.232.202.119), but no problems if I use "127.0.0.1" or "192.168.2.50" My ports are forwarded, and I tested them online.

Comment: How do you expect to receive some answer, after your code is way too far from being readable ? :)

Comment: It somehow fixed itself.

Comment: Rolled back. It's better to have the code visible on the site. For the code formatting to work you just have to separate the code block from other text by an empty line, just like you would separate paragraphs of text.

Comment: Is this the version of the code that gives the error? Both server and client are creating the ObjectOutputStream first, which means neither side would be left hanging waiting to read the object stream header.

Comment: It doesn't have the error if I use it in my network, if I use my external IP, it gives these errors. It's intended to be a multiplayer lobby for Age of Empires 3.

Comment: setSoTimeout(0) merely reasserts the default, which is an infinite timeout. You got a read timeout, which is impossible with this code. Therefore this is not your real code. Not a real question.

Comment: I know. It is my real code, that is why I'm asking a question. Should I post all of my code? And thats why I added the timeout. Again, this is only on my external IP, that's why it makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, that's impossible. You cannot get a SocketTimeoutException by setting the timeout to zero. You may as well remove that line: it has no effect.

Comment: I know. I get the timeout exception client-side. And when I call the socket.getInputStream(), to create the objectinputstream. It's waiting for the outputstream of the client to flush, but it already has? This is my dilemma.

Comment: *Remove the setSoTimeout() call.* I will add that you shouldn't be using network operations in the event dispatching thread, e.g. in window listeners. You need to completely reconstruct your code anyway to fix that, by using separate threads. I suggest you do that and then retest.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question died, but for google's sake, to fix this, check if the client's external ip matches the server's ip, and if it does, use a local address. What causes it? It's your router. In some models, WAN security prevents local computers from acting like remote computers. I don't see a security problem with this, but apparently, router companies do. I tried to call my company and have my wan security disabled, to find out, that it's not possible.